# Capture image from streaming video on panel .NET C#

Tags: c#, video, bitmap, panel, capture

I'm days trying to solve something that still can not.

I am developing a monitoring system that sends a stream for a panel object.

I need to extract an image Bitmap panel of getting the frame of that stream every 1 second.

I've tried using the following code:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(m_viewerPanel.Width, m_viewerPanel.Height);
Rectangle imageRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, m_viewerPanel.Width, m_viewerPanel.Height);
m_viewerPanel.DrawToBitmap(bmp, imageRect);
bmp.Save(@"C:\Users\Fabio\Desktop\imagens\cam" + DateTime.Now.Ticks + ".jpeg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

This code can generate the Bitmap, but not the contents of that panel would have to show where the frame of the video.

The code responsible for displaying streaming is a video SDK vigilance, and from what I understand, uses DirectX9.

Please help me solve this. I'm trying days and still did not get. This project is already late because of that and no longer know what to do.

Thank U.

Comment: Many though not all ways of displaying video defeat all simple attempts to capture them. You may want to try if you can use the system keys (PrintScreen) to get it into the clipboard. If that fails I doubt anything will work except possibly plugging into DirectX, but I don't know anything about that topic. Of course the first place to look would be the SDK's documentation..!

Comment: Try to disable overlay rendering. As long as the video is rendered to an overlay window, capturing will be hard without access to the render graph.